# How to display progress bar visible to end user when Java program is looping through thousands of data?

Tags: javascript, java, for-loop, servlets, progress-bar

I have a Java method with one for loop. The loop iterates over thousands of data and it takes lots of time. In this case I want to show progress status to the ends users of my program.

I have used `JProgressBar` with `JFrame`, but it only works when program runs in local machine. When I deploy application to remote server(production server) and run it, the progress bar doesn't appear.

Below is my method:

```
public List<EmployeeDetail> getEmployeeDetail(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String org) {
    List<EmployeeDetail> employeeDetailList = new ArrayList<EmployeeDetail>();
    List<Employee> employeeList = getEmployee(org);

    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    String query = "SELECT EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, START_DATE " + " FROM EMPLOYEE_HISTORY_TABLE "
            + "WHERE EMPLOYEE_NUMBER =?";

    DatabaseConnection dbConnection = new DatabaseConnection();

    // --progress bar starts---

    // Create frame for dialog box
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("searching data...");

    // creates progress bar
    final JProgressBar pb = new JProgressBar(0, EmployeeList.size());
    pb.setStringPainted(true);

    // add progress bar
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.getContentPane().add(pb);

    frame.setSize(300, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    int counterForProgressBar = 0;
    for (Employee Employee : EmployeeList) {
        try {
            con = dbConnection.getConnectionDetails();
            // --Progress bar continues--
            final int currentValue = counterForProgressBar;

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    pb.setValue(currentValue);
                }
            });
            java.lang.Thread.sleep(100);

            // --Progress bar ends---

            String firstName = Employee.getFirstName();
            String lastName = Employee.getLastName();

            String personNumber = Employee.getPersonNumber;


            st = con.prepareStatement(query);
            st.setString(1, personNumber);
            rs = st.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                String employee_number = rs.getString("EMPLOYEE_NUMBER");
                Date START_DATE = rs.getDate("START_DATE");

                EmployeeDetail employeeDetail = new EmployeeDetail(firstName, lastName, employee_number, START_DATE);
                employeeDetailList.add(employeeDetail);
            }
            counterForProgressBar++;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                con.close();
                st.close();
                rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    // When data search process completes close the progress bar
    frame.dispose();
    return employeeDetailList;
}
```

Would you please help me how to show progress bar/status in this case?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: you can call this method "getEmployeeDetail" using jquery Ajax method. In your ajax you can use custom loader at beforeSend and hide the loader in 'success' method

Comment: @sony Would you please provide some example (sample code or links) if you have?

Comment: you can try this tutorial. It will show you a Ajax loader until the content loads from DB. URL: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_ajaxcomplete

Comment: @GhostCat I want progress bar to be seen when my end users run the application from anywhere. I have tomcat in remote server windows server 2012. I created a WAR file of my program and deployed/copied it to this tomcat server. Then I access the application remotely. This time no progress bar appears. You have any other solution for this problem?

Comment: @sony Thank you for the link. I will have a look into it.

Comment: @GhostCat I am new in developer field so I am trying to understand how AJAX works and how to implement it to my java method. if you have other suitable materials please do suggest me... and ofcourse if I am able to do I will accept the suggestion and votes up :)

Comment: @GhostCat Thank you for help..  I will do that  :-)

Comment: @GhostCat I am still unsucceessful to implement this feature that's why there is no comment from my side and I am still trying :( My apology for this.

Answer (score 0):

you should do your hardwork (big looping) on an other thread in an asynchronous way. like that you let your UI thread reactive to the user and in the same time, you can send the work progress to the UI thread. there are many examples to do that in the internet..

Comment: could you possibly suggest me suitable examples/materials?

Comment: this link may help you https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html

Comment: I have used Jprogress and JFrame from the link you have provided but it didn't help :(

Comment: there is no error in the log file. According to GhostCat, JFrame only runs in machine where java code runs, may be because of that. What you think Brom?

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in comments: a JFrame runs on the machine that runs that java code. So, first of all: your idea to use a JFrame does **not** work. Plain and simple.

Now the real question is: how do users of your service interact with that remote server? As: the real answer is that you have to provide that "progress information" within the "client side" of your application.

As you tagged with *servlet*, I suggest you look into using Ajax to provide progress information, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829708/setting-up-ajax-progress-bar) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will have a look on your example